# difference between SenTesting OCUnit and GHUnit Testing

Tags: iphone, testing

Can any one tell me difference between senTesting,OCUnit and GHUnit Testing difference.

Is SenTesting and OCUnit both are same?

please tag if you have any related documents

@thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OCUnit includes SenTestingKit. OCUnit ships with Xcode.

GHUnit is an alternative testing kit. It used to get used a lot in preference to SenTestingKit due to certain limitations of SenTestingKit (such as inability to set breakpoints in test classes). However, those limitation have been removed in recent versions of SenTestingKit.

So to summarise, SenTestingKit is a good choice these days.

This blog post describes the situation very well:

http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/04/15/unit-testing-in-xcode-4-use-ocunit-and-sentest-instead-of-ghunit/